# What's the difference between 'most', 'most of', and 'almost'?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between **most**, **most of**, and **almost**?

Which one should I use in the following sentence?

> **Most** students passed the test.

or

> **Most of** students passed the test.

or

> **Almost** students passed the test.

Comment: As a learner: Where did you see the last sentence? Almost is an adverb, I guess it should be something like "almost ***all the*** students passed the test". However, I guess you may hear that in a very rare scenario in which different groups took the test and the student, not the other groups like workers, etc., passed the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context.

Use most to refer to a quantity of an unspecific group.  We use most when we are speaking in general and do not have a specific group of people or things in mind.

Most students pass the test. (Speaking generally about an undefined population)

Use most of the X to refer to a quantity of a specific group. Note the expression includes a phrase defining the number to a specific group.

Most of the students (of my class/school etc.) passed the test. (Speaking about a specific sample of the population)

Ref: http://www.grammar-quizzes.com

Almost can be used with expressions of time and quantity. In other words you have to define the quantity.

Almost half of the students passed the test.